# Redirect the non-www version of the site to the www

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

In wordpress site how to Redirect the non-www version of the site to the www version to remove duplicate content

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup it in your .htaccess file, it should looks like this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: After change it not working.

Comment: I have updated the code. I forgot to add `,L` directive to the redirection rule. It should work now.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov you need a `/` before `$1` in the RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks @Geert, it was early morning when I wrote it. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

This code is similar to Eugene’s, but it will redirect *any* domain that is not your main domain with “www” to the correct address. Handy if you have multiple top-level domains.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# These are the lines that do the trick
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourdomain.com/$0 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hello geert, till my site not redirect. any other solution for redirecting www and non-www.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http:www.//demo.yourdomain.com/realestate/$
RewriteRule (.*) demo.yourdomain.com/realestate/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: Note that you need to put the my code above the WP code in the `.htaccess`. Also, make sure your Apache server has the mod_rewrite module installed.

Comment: hellow geert i put the code in .htaccess. But it redirect out of the site.

Comment: You did change "yourdomain.com" to your own domain, did you?

Comment: yes i change. any other changer i need do done?